# What should be done if getting error:can only assign an iterable while applying a function on dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am applying a function code string_match_score to a dataframe and getting type error:can only assign an iterable.Can anyone please tell me what that means and how to solve it? or what's the right way to apply the function?Below are the codes and dataframe.

```
def convert_to_list(string):
list1=[]
list1[:0]=string
return list1

def string_match_score(s1,s2,country1,country2):

list_1 = convert_to_list(s1)
list_2 = convert_to_list(s2)

if s1=="" or s2=="":
    return 0
elif s1==s2:
    return 1
elif country1 == "ax" and country2=="ax" and len(s1)==10 and len(s2)==13 and s1[:10]==s2[:10]:
    return 90
elif country1 == "ax" and country2=="ax" and len(s2)==10 and len(s1)==13 and s1[:10]==s2[:10]:
    return 90
elif len(list_1) != len(list_2):
    return 0
elif len(list_1) == len(list_2):
    # index variable
    idx = 0
    # Result list
    res = []
    # With iteration
    for i in list_1:
        if i != list_2[idx]:
            res.append(idx)
        idx = idx + 1
    if len(res) >= 3:
        return 0
    elif len(res) == 1:
        return 89
    elif len(res) == 2:
        if res[1] - res[0] != 1:
            return 0
        elif res[1] - res[0] == 1:
            if list_1[res[0]] == list_2[res[1]] and list_1[res[1]] == list_2[res[0]]:
                 return 78
            
            else: 
                return 0

    df['final_score']=df.apply(lambda x: 
    string_match_score(x["ID1"],x["ID2"],x["Country1"],x["Country2"]),axis=1)


S.No    Country1    ID1 Country2    ID2
   1    ax                ax      99577A09
   2    US           QWE    US     9957700B
   3    Mexico    81231828  US    81231826
   4    US      81321862    US     81231862
```

Comment: Did you copy you code right? Indentation is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the indentation in your definitions are wrong. It should look like this:

```
def convert_to_list(string):
    list1=[]
    
    return list1

def string_match_score(s1,s2,country1,country2):

    list_1 = convert_to_list(s1)
    list_2 = convert_to_list(s2)

    if s1=="" or s2=="":
        return 0
    elif s1==s2:
        return 1
    elif country1 == "ax" and country2=="ax" and len(s1)==10 and len(s2)==13 and s1[:10]==s2[:10]:
        return 90
    elif country1 == "ax" and country2=="ax" and len(s2)==10 and len(s1)==13 and s1[:10]==s2[:10]:
        return 90
    elif len(list_1) != len(list_2):
        return 0
    elif len(list_1) == len(list_2):
        # index variable
        idx = 0
        # Result list
        res = []
        # With iteration
        for i in list_1:
            if i != list_2[idx]:
                res.append(idx)
            idx = idx + 1
        if len(res) >= 3:
            return 0
        elif len(res) == 1:
            return 89
        elif len(res) == 2:
            if res[1] - res[0] != 1:
                return 0
            elif res[1] - res[0] == 1:
                if list_1[res[0]] == list_2[res[1]] and list_1[res[1]] == list_2[res[0]]:
                     return 78

                else: 
                    return 0
```

Secondly, the error you get comes from the `list1` in you first function because you can only assign an iterable to a slice; something with 0 or more values, not one specific value. Delete it. Then, it works.

Example: Take this df

```
S.No Country1       ID1 Country2       ID2
0     1   Mexico   8554433       US   8554433
1     2       US  34893434       US  99593434
2     3   Mexico  81231828       US  81231826
3     4       US  81321862       US  81231862
```

an apply your function:

```
df['final_score']=df.apply(lambda x: 
    string_match_score(x["ID1"],x["ID2"],x["Country1"],x["Country2"]),axis=1)
```

returns

```
S.No Country1       ID1 Country2       ID2  final_score
0     1   Mexico   8554433       US   8554433          1.0
1     2       US  34893434       US  99593434          NaN
2     3   Mexico  81231828       US  81231826          NaN
3     4       US  81321862       US  81231862          NaN
```